# Do regular Wiimotes work on the Wii-U?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, wii-u

I went all in when the Wii came out and got 4 Wii-motes right away.
I do not want to buy new Wii-motes to play party games if I get the Wii-U. I mean it seems silly if everyone just needs the D-pad to make Mario run.

The only thing I've heard is that Wii-motion plus Wii-motes will be compatible with the Wii-U from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_U) article.
Is there a definitive word from Nintendo that regular Wii-motes will not work with the Wii-U or has anyone tried this at home?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, regular Wiimotes are supported by the Wii-U.

[This page](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/games/oms/wii_u/packs_accessories.html) on Nintendo's website says:

> **Controllers**
>
> The Wii U console is capable of supporting two Wii U GamePad controllers, up to four Wii Remote (or Wii Remote Plus) controllers or Wii U Pro Controllers, and Wii accessories such as the Nunchuk, Classic Controller and Wii Balance Board.

Comment: Update: I can confirm that the system will work with "original" Wii Remotes, but only for games that aren't using the Plus motion controls. Pretty much the same way Wii did it.

Comment: Good Guy Nintendo ladies and gents

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2011-06-08-will-wii-u-support-original-wiimote) article from Eurogamer seems to suggest that it doesn't.

> Nintendo's Wii U console will not support original models of the Wii controller without a MotionPlus attachment, according to comments made by Shigeru Miyamoto.

Comment: Good find. I feel it is still a bit ambiguous though. M- `Right now I'm planning that people can still be able to use their Wii Remote controllers that they already have, which means this time you now have five controllers to play with.` I-  `You mean this new controller, and four Wii Remote Plus controllers for a total of five.` M-  `Right. Five controllers.`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but only on games like Mario.  Call of Duty will need the motion plus wiimote unless you are in the wii software on your wiiu.  If you did not know your wii is two different consoles with a channel to switch back and forth between them.