# Do old Wiimotes with Wii MotionPlus attachment work on Wii U?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

I have two old Wiimotes without built-in MotionPlus but I have two MotionPlus attachments for them. If I use the MotionPlus attachment can I use these Wiimotes with the Wii U or do I have to buy the new Wiimotes with built-in MotionPlus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do regular Wiimotes work on the Wii-U?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93445/do-regular-wiimotes-work-on-the-wii-u)

Comment: @TrentHawkins: That question doesn't mention MotionPlus though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/631516-wii-u/64155948 it works and http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/wii-u-support-wiimotes-with-wii-plsu-attachment-or-not.452723128/ says that the wii u can't tell the difference. Even a regular one without an attachment will work on games that do not require the added functionality, however of course games that need the WM+ require the attachment.

Comment: I'll confirm that link with experience: I have used a Wii w/ MotionPlus attachments, and they work fine on the nintendoland minigames which require MotionPlus (e.g. metroid plus, and zelda battle quest).